# Difference between spread operator and without spread operator in react-redux reducers

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

In react-redux, everyone uses spread operator to return the existing state and then add a new payload like `[...state,action.payload ]`, but I have a situation where in reducers they are returning `action.payload` directly and I am unable to understand the difference between them.

My reducer looks like this:

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
     switch(action.type){
        case 'FETCH_POSTS':
            return action.payload; //I have doubt here
        default:
            return state;
     }

}
```

What if I put in return statement as `return [...state,action.payload ]`.
Can you please tell me the difference in both?

I have googled and tried to implement both of the above scenarios but I don't understand it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely dependent on what `action.payload` contains and what the `action` is.

In this scenario:

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
     switch(action.type){
        case 'FETCH_POSTS':
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
     }

}
```

The `action.payload` likely contains an array of objects that came from a back-end API. This is acceptable since your original state wants to accept an array that includes information on All posts. The array requirement is met.

Where as a scenario like this:

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
     switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_POST':
            return [...state, action.payload]; 
        default:
            return state;
     }

}
```

That `ADD_POST` action appends new data to the existing state. But, in this case, `action.payload` is a single object `{}`. if you only returned `action.payload`, your state will only have that object `{}`.  The reason why they use the `spread operator [...]` is so that they can retain the already existing posts in the state. You want to keep the old-posts and add the new one into the array.

Lastly you can condense these both to just:

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
     switch(action.type){
        case 'FETCH_POSTS':
            return action.payload; //get list from API, payload is an array
        case 'ADD_POST':
            return [...state, action.payload] //add new post to end of list, payload is an object.
        default:
            return state;
     }

}
```

Comment: So if I put "action.payload" only or "[...state,action.payload]",both will be same ? Yeah the action is fetching a list of posts from backend api .

Comment: They serve different purposes depending on what action.payload is. If action.payload is an array of posts [{...}, {...}, {...}]  then it makes sense to just return action.payload because your state wants an array value. But, if action.payload is an object, like a new post, then you dont want to lose the existing posts by only returning action.payload. Instead, you want to add the post to the existing list by doing [...state, action.payload] @ArjunKumar